# MySQL query multi data from same column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, pivot

I have this two tables and i would like to output the following result.

```
Table A
-----------------------------
ID | Name
1  | John
2  | Doe
-----------------------------

Table B
-----------------------------
ID | FK | Type | Point
1  | 1  | 1    | 10
2  | 1  | 2    | 15
3  | 1  | 3    | 15
4  | 2  | 1    | 8
5  | 2  | 2    | 6
6  | 2  | 3    | 5
-----------------------------


Expected Output
-----------------------------
ID | Name | Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | Total
1  | John | 10    | 15    | 15    | 40
2  | Doe  | 8     | 6     | 5     | 19
-----------------------------
```

Another question is should I index Table B, FK & Type column for better performance?

Appreciated everyone helps in advanced :)

Comment: Surely the community can help, please share the query with us that you have created.

Comment: Search SO for `[mysql] [pivot]` you will find hundreds of similar questions with answer.

Comment: thanks Barmar! finally i got the right keyword to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Name, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN B.Type = 1 THEN B.Point ELSE 0 END) Type1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN B.Type = 2 THEN B.Point ELSE 0 END) Type2, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN B.Type = 3 THEN B.Point ELSE 0 END) Type3, 
       SUM(B.Point) Total
FROM tableA a 
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON A.ID = B.FK 
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Comment: Thanks Shah! Your sql statement saved my headache. I got your idea now.

Comment: @WaiMun You're most welcome... You can also check how to use stackoverflow use this link http://stackoverflow.com/tour